# Java: How can I wait for the updateUI?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I was doing a demo on the ChessBoard Game.I guess you must know it.How ever I meet with a problem.The result just show to quickly.I want to see how it works out slowly.

Here is the main code:

```
public void ChessBoard(int tr, int tc, int dr, int dc, int size) throws InterruptedException   {
        if (size == 1) {
            return;
        }
        Random rd = new Random();
        float red = rd.nextFloat();
        float green = rd.nextFloat();
        float blue = rd.nextFloat();
        Color col = new Color(red, green, blue);
        int s = size / 2;
        if (dr < tr + s && dc < tc + s) {
            ChessBoard(tr, tc, dr, dc, s);
        } else {
            button[tr + s - 1][tc + s - 1].setBackground(col);
            ChessBoard(tr, tc, tr + s - 1, tc + s - 1, s);
        }
        if (dr < tr + s && dc >= tc + s) {
            ChessBoard(tr, tc + s, dr, dc, s);
        } else {
            button[tr + s - 1][tc + s].setBackground(col);
            ChessBoard(tr, tc + s, tr + s - 1, tc + s, s);
        }
        if (dr >= tr + s && dc < tc + s) {
            ChessBoard(tr + s, tc, dr, dc, s);
        } else {
            button[tr + s][tc + s - 1].setBackground(col);
            ChessBoard(tr + s, tc, tr + s, tc + s - 1, s);

        }
        if (dr >= tr + s && dc >= tc + s) {
            ChessBoard(tr + s, tc + s, dr, dc, s);
        } else {
            button[tr + s][tc + s].setBackground(col);
            ChessBoard(tr + s, tc + s, tr + s, tc + s, s);
        }


        mainPanel.updateUI();
        for (long i=1;i<10000;i++){
            for (long j=0;j<10000;j++){
                i+=1;
                i-=1;
            }
        }

    }
```

But the result just turned out in a flash!It seems the mainPanel didn't finished its job.
The mainJanel is a JPanel object.

Comment: Maybe you should put the code for drawing different parts of the animation in different methods, then, call them one at a time, with a sleep in between? Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also add the sleep at the beginning, but only the progress is slow down, it seems has nothing to do with the showing up

It appears your code is executing on the Event Dispatch Thread. You should NEVER tell the EDT to sleep(). This prevents the GUI from repainting itself. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Instead you should be using a Swing Timer to schedule the animation of each move. The tutorial also has a section on Timers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion!I'm trying on it:)

Answer (score 2):

updateUI is used to change the look&feel of the component. To redraw the contents of the panel you should use

```
mainPanel.repaint()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Thread.sleep( /* time in milliseconds */ )` to slow the execution.

Comment: The progress is slowed down. However the result still comes out in a sudden. All the button changed their color in a second.

Comment: You have to use mainPanel.redraw() every step as `Francisco Puga` mentioned.

Comment: yeah. I've changed to repaint(). I also add the sleep at the beginning, but only the progress is slow down, it seems has nothing to do with the showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Halting execution with [`sleep`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) .

Example

```
public class SleepMessages {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        String importantInfo[] = {
            "Mares eat oats",
            "Does eat oats",
            "Little lambs eat ivy",
            "A kid will eat ivy too"
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < importantInfo.length; i++) {
            //Pause for 4 seconds
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            //Print a message
            System.out.println(importantInfo[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This way it would slow down your program.

```
 //Pause for 4 seconds
   Thread.sleep(4000);
```

Comment: This example works with it. However it only can slow down the progress not the speed of the result